# Merge two data frames on closest timestamp by id and maximum difference in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, merge

I have two data frames that I'm trying to combine. They must be joined based on the closest `timestamp` for a certain `ID`, if the time difference is lower than a certain value (e.g. 10 minutes). So every `timestamp` in `df1` needs to be matched with the closest `timestamp` in `df2` for a given ID. If the difference in time is over a certain value, it should be `NA`. I've tried multiple ways of combining them using `sqldf` and `nearestTimeandID` but can't seem to succeed. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what the data looks like:

```
# dput(head(df1))

structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1660048051, 1660049817, 
1660051642, 1660053416, 1660055228, 1660057017), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), location_long = c(2.7305546, 2.730441, 
2.7301144, 2.732173, 2.7319352, 2.7319432), location_lat = c(51.1519968, 
51.1520704, 51.1519392, 51.1509984, 51.1511456, 51.1511168), 
    ID = c("16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba", 
    "16000002ba", "16000002ba")), row.names = c("1.1", "1.2", 
"1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6"), class = "data.frame")

# dput(head(df2))

structure(list(ID = c("16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba", 
"16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba"), Collecting_time = c("2022-08-07 23:59:05 UTC", 
"2022-08-08 00:00:03 UTC", "2022-08-08 00:30:39 UTC", "2022-08-08 01:00:16 UTC", 
"2022-08-08 01:30:51 UTC", "2022-08-08 02:00:25 UTC"), ODBA = c(110L, 
290L, 260L, 220L, 210L, 410L)), row.names = 290345:290350, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share `dput(head(df1))` and same for `df2`?

Comment: Added the dput version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the {powerjoin} package and specify the `by` argument using formulas. I too, edited the first entry of `df1` to get at least one join. And I proprossed `df2` so that we actually have a date time object.

I was not sure if the time intervall is +/- 10 minutes or if it is only smaller than 10 minutes, below I applied the latter, but you can play around with the settings.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(powerjoin)

df2 <- df2 |>
  mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(Collecting_time, tz = "UTC"))

power_left_join(
  df1,
  df2,
  by = c("ID",
         ~ difftime(.y$timestamp, .x$timestamp, units = "mins") < 10,
         ~ difftime(.y$timestamp, .x$timestamp, units = "mins") > 0)
)
#>           timestamp.x location_long location_lat         ID
#> 1 2022-08-09 12:27:31      2.730555     51.15200 16000002ba
#> 2 2022-08-09 12:56:57      2.730441     51.15207 16000002ba
#> 3 2022-08-09 13:27:22      2.730114     51.15194 16000002ba
#> 4 2022-08-09 13:56:56      2.732173     51.15100 16000002ba
#> 5 2022-08-09 14:27:08      2.731935     51.15115 16000002ba
#> 6 2022-08-09 14:56:57      2.731943     51.15112 16000002ba
#>           Collecting_time ODBA         timestamp.y
#> 1 2022-08-09 12:36:00 UTC  110 2022-08-09 12:36:00
#> 2                    <NA>   NA                <NA>
#> 3                    <NA>   NA                <NA>
#> 4                    <NA>   NA                <NA>
#> 5                    <NA>   NA                <NA>
#> 6                    <NA>   NA                <NA>
```

Data from OP

```r
df1 <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1660048051, 1660049817, 
                                       1660051642, 1660053416, 1660055228, 1660057017), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                  "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), location_long = c(2.7305546, 2.730441, 
                                                                                                                                               2.7301144, 2.732173, 2.7319352, 2.7319432), location_lat = c(51.1519968, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            51.1520704, 51.1519392, 51.1509984, 51.1511456, 51.1511168), 
               ID = c("16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba", 
                      "16000002ba", "16000002ba")), row.names = c("1.1", "1.2", 
                                                                  "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6"), class = "data.frame")


df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba", 
                      "16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba"), Collecting_time = c("2022-08-09 12:36:00 UTC", 
                                                                                     "2022-08-08 00:00:03 UTC", "2022-08-08 00:30:39 UTC", "2022-08-08 01:00:16 UTC", 
                                                                                     "2022-08-08 01:30:51 UTC", "2022-08-08 02:00:25 UTC"), ODBA = c(110L, 
                                                                                                                                                     290L, 260L, 220L, 210L, 410L)), row.names = 290345:290350, class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have understood you correctly. But maybe this will help. Note that I edited first entry of df2 to get an actual match.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

df1 <-
structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1660048051, 1660049817, 
                                       1660051642, 1660053416, 1660055228, 1660057017), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                  "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), location_long = c(2.7305546, 2.730441, 
                                                                                                                                               2.7301144, 2.732173, 2.7319352, 2.7319432), location_lat = c(51.1519968, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            51.1520704, 51.1519392, 51.1509984, 51.1511456, 51.1511168), 
               ID = c("16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba", 
                      "16000002ba", "16000002ba")), row.names = c("1.1", "1.2", 
                                                                  "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6"), class = "data.frame")

df2 <-

structure(list(ID = c("16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba", 
                      "16000002ba", "16000002ba", "16000002ba"), Collecting_time = c("2022-08-09 12:36:05 UTC", 
                                                                                     "2022-08-08 00:00:03 UTC", "2022-08-08 00:30:39 UTC", "2022-08-08 01:00:16 UTC", 
                                                                                     "2022-08-08 01:30:51 UTC", "2022-08-08 02:00:25 UTC"), ODBA = c(110L, 
timing <- 10                                                                                                                                                 290L, 260L, 220L, 210L, 410L)), row.names = 290345:290350, class = "data.frame")

# Convert Collecting_time to POSIXct format
df2$Collecting_time <- as.POSIXct(df2$Collecting_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")

# Join df1 and df2 based on the closest timestamp within x minutes defined in "timing" for each ID
df_join <- fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, 
                           by = c("ID" = "ID", "timestamp" = "Collecting_time"),
                           match_fun = list(`==`, function(x, y) abs(difftime(x, y, units = "mins")) <= timing))


# Select the columns you need
df_join <- select(df_join, timestamp, location_long, location_lat, ID.x, Collecting_time, ODBA)


# Rename the columns
names(df_join)[5] <- "closest_Collecting_time"
names(df_join)[6] <- "ODBA_of_closest_timestamp"


df_join
```

Comment: This is indeed what I meant, and works, but the other proposed solution is quite a bit faster. Thanks!